# Interface implementation with abstract class input parameters

Tags: c#

I want to understand interface implementation because I have been having errors that doesn't make sense to me.
I have this interface and 2 abstract classes:

```
public interface ICashBuddieHelper
{
    IHelper FilterOnContext(DbBuddieContext db);
    IHelper PrepareResultModel(InputModelBase message);
    IHelper SortSet();
    ResultModelBase ToResultModel(InputModelBase message);
}

public abstract class ResultModelBase
{
    ...
}

public abstract class InputModelBase
{
    ...
}
```

and I have two classes that implement this Helper interface but with more derived versions of the input parameters and return types which are abstract classes as shown above.
I have implemented the IHelper interface with the following classes

```
public class BankAccountHelper : ICashBuddieHelper
{
    public ICashBuddieHelper FilterOnContext(DbBuddieContext db){...}
    public ICashBuddieHelper PrepareResultModel(BankAccountInputModel message){...}//error
    public ICashBuddieHelper SortSet(){...}
    public ResultModelBase ToResultModel(BankAccountInputModel message){...}//error
}

public class CashFlowHelper : ICashBuddieHelper
{
    public ICashBuddieHelper FilterOnContext(DbBuddieContext db){...}
    public ICashBuddieHelper PrepareResultModel(CashFlowInputModel message){...}//error
    public ICashBuddieHelper SortSet(){...}
    public ResultModelBase ToResultModel(CashFlowInputModel message){...}//error
}
```

From the code snippet above, you can see that two lines in the implementing classes give the error that says:

> 'CashFlowHelper' does not implement interface member 'ICashBuddieHelper.PrepareResultModel(InputModelBase)'
>   'CashFlowHelper' does not implement interface member 'ICashBuddieHelper.ToResultModel(InputModelBase)'

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I would like to understand my misunderstanding of interfaces. Surely I can use a more derived type in the place of an abstract class. I don't understand what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: You're missing `public` in CashFlowHelper (in front of the interface method signatures). The interface requires that they're public.

Comment: Adding to @john's answer: if you want to hide interface member, make it explicit. For instance, `void IMyInterface.DoSomething { }`.

Comment: sorry john i didn't just add public while adding it here on stackoverlow. I will add that to it now. Thanks

Comment: Please paste your error messages as text. Search engines and people with slow networks will be thankful :)

Comment: ok @NoelWidmer will do that.

Comment: FYI Your code appears to work fine. See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1PuEge). Sometimes when I'm implementing classes, etc. I press `Ctrl+.` and just hit `Enter`, and because I've gone too fast, I accidentally end up with a new class in the local namespace with the same name as a class in another namespace. Is there a chance you have done this? Or a chance that the implementation and interface refer to two distinct classes with the same name?

Comment: @JosephIzang The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Nkosi you just don't understand the question that's all. I was just pointed me to fiddle and I have the same thing and its running fine on fiddle and so I am taking his suggestion as a first step towards getting a solution to this.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to do a clean and rebuild, and open/close VS in case it's just Intellisense having a bit of a weird moment.

Comment: Thanks @john but still nothing. I did a clean, rebuild and restarted VS and still nothing.

Comment: I saw an error in the code I pasted here on stackoverflow and it is the input parameters of the Helper derived classes. I have modified them again and hope the question is clearer. Sorry @Nkosi you were right, I made a mistake in the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely I can use a more derived type in the place of an abstract
>   class. I don't understand what the compiler is complaining about.

Referenceing [interface (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)

> An interface contains only the signatures of methods, properties,
>   events or indexers. A class or struct that implements the interface
>   **must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition**.

*note: emphasis mine*

The interface is a contract that any derived class must follow.

The compiler makes no assumption between

```
ICashBuddieHelper PrepareResultModel(InputModelBase message);
```

and

```
public ICashBuddieHelper PrepareResultModel(BankAccountInputModel message)
```

regarless of `BankAccountInputModel` being derived from `InputModelBase`.

As far as the compiler is concerned those are two different definitions and that you broke the contract by not implementing the interface as defined. Hence the compile error.

> where then can I use my derived type i.e BankAccountInputModel? Or
>   rather how then do I use a base type in an interface and get to use a
>   more derived version of that type?

One possibility you could consider is using [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/), which is a whole other topic in itself but look at the following example that refactors the interface and uses your previously defined types.

```
public interface ICashBuddieHelper<T> where T : InputModelBase {
    ICashBuddieHelper<T> FilterOnContext(DbBuddieContext db);
    ICashBuddieHelper<T> PrepareResultModel(T message);
    ICashBuddieHelper<T> SortSet();
    ResultModelBase ToResultModel(T message);
}


public class BankAccountInputModel : InputModelBase {
    //...
}

public class BankAccountHelper : ICashBuddieHelper<BankAccountInputModel> {
    public ICashBuddieHelper<BankAccountInputModel> FilterOnContext(DbBuddieContext db) { return null; }
    public ICashBuddieHelper<BankAccountInputModel> PrepareResultModel(BankAccountInputModel message) {
        return null;
    }
    public ICashBuddieHelper<BankAccountInputModel> SortSet() { return null; }
    public ResultModelBase ToResultModel(BankAccountInputModel message) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How every this may add more complexity than is necessary.

I suggest reviewing your design choices.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes don't actualy derive from the interface, add : IHelper to each of the classes, as in:

```
public class BankAccountHelper : IHelper
```

Comment: sorry again a mistake by me. Haven't slept for a bit probably. My apologies. I will change this now.